# Number of Count is not increasing After Clicking Add to Cart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I was trying to implement Add to cart in my project. The state in App.tsx of cart section is not changing after clicking add to cart button. I want to show increase the count of the add to cart items in my navbar.
All the required libraries are installed. My site is running as well. But Count is not increasing.
App tsx

```
import { Button,Badge, Container, Form, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer.js'
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Store } from './Store.js'

function App() {

  const {
     
    state: { mode, cart },
    dispatch,
  } = useContext(Store)

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', mode)
  }, [mode])
  const switchModeHandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH_MODE' })
  }

  return (
   

    <div className="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
      <header>
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand >
              <Link to={`/`} className="no-underline">
                ThriftTrade
              </Link>
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="/buy">Buy</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/sell">Sell</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/offers">Offers</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/auction">Auction</Nav.Link>

              <Nav.Link href="/categories">Categories</Nav.Link>

   
              <Nav.Link href="/about_us">About Us</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Form className="d-flex">
              <Form.Control
                type="search"
                placeholder="Search"
                className="me-2"
                aria-label="Search"
              />
              <Button variant="dark">Search</Button>
            </Form>
          </Container>

          <Nav>
          <Link to="/cart" className="nav-link">
              Cart
          
              {cart.cartItems.length > 0 && (
                <Badge pill bg="danger">
                  {cart.cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity, 0)
                 
                  }
                 
                </Badge>
              )}
            </Link>
            <a href="/login" className="nav-link">
              Sign In
            </a>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </header>

      <main>
        {/* <Container> */}
        <Outlet />
        {/* </Container> */}
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

utilis.ts

```
import { ApiError } from './types/Apierror.js'
import { CartItem } from './types/Cart.js'
import { Product } from './types/Product.js'
export const getError = (error: ApiError) => {
  return error.response && error.response.data.message
    ? error.response.data.message
    : error.message
}

export const convertProductToCartItem = (product: Product): CartItem => {
  const cartItem: CartItem = {
    _id: product._id,
    name: product.name,
    slug: product.slug,
    image: product.image,
    price: product.price,
    countInStock: product.countInStock,
    quantity: 1,
  }
  return cartItem
}
```

ProductItem.tsx

```
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Product } from '../types/Product.js'
import Rating from './Rating.js'
import { convertProductToCartItem } from '../utils.js'
import { Store } from '../Store.js'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { CartItem } from '../types/Cart.js'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
function ProductItem({ product }: { product: Product }) {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store)
  const {
    cart: { cartItems },
  } = state

  const addToCartHandler = (item: CartItem) => {
    const existItem = cartItems.find((x) => x._id === product._id)
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1
    if (product.countInStock < quantity) {
      alert('Sorry. Product is out of stock')
      return
    }
    dispatch({
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: { ...item, quantity },
    })
    toast.success('Product added to the cart')
  }

  return (
    <Card>
      <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
        <img src={product.image} className="card-img-top" alt={product.name} />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        <Link className="product_name_class" to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
          <Card.Title className="product-name">{product.name}</Card.Title>
        </Link>
        <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} />
        <Card.Text>${product.price}</Card.Text>
        {product.countInStock === 0 ? (
          <Button variant="light" disabled>
            Out of stock
          </Button>
        ) : (
          
          <Button
            onClick={() => addToCartHandler(convertProductToCartItem(product))}
          >
            Add to cart
          </Button>
        )}
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default ProductItem
```

Store.tsx

```
import React from "react";

import { Cart, CartItem } from "./types/Cart.js";

// Define the AppState type
type AppState = {
  mode: string;
  cart: Cart;
};

// Define the initial state
const initialState: AppState = {
  mode: localStorage.getItem("mode") ?? (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches ? "dark" : "light"),
  cart: {
    cartItems: localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")!)
      : [],
    shippingAddress: localStorage.getItem("shippingAddress")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shippingAddress")!)
      : {},
    paymentMethod: localStorage.getItem("paymentMethod") ?? "PayPal",
    itemsPrice: 0,
    shippingPrice: 0,
    taxPrice: 0,
    totalPrice: 0,
  },
};

// Define the supported actions
type Action =
  | { type: "SWITCH_MODE" }
  | { type: "CART_ADD_ITEM"; payload: CartItem }
  | { type: "UPDATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS"; payload: Cart["shippingAddress"] };

// Define the reducer function
function reducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SWITCH_MODE": {
      const mode = state.mode === "dark" ? "light" : "dark";
      localStorage.setItem("mode", mode);
      return { ...state, mode };
    }

    case "CART_ADD_ITEM": {
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find((item: CartItem) => item._id === newItem._id);
      const cartItems = existItem
        ? state.cart.cartItems.map((item: CartItem) => (item._id === existItem._id ? newItem : item))
        : [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];

      localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));

      return { ...state, cart: { ...state.cart, cartItems } };
    }

    case "UPDATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS": {
      const shippingAddress = action.payload;

      localStorage.setItem("shippingAddress", JSON.stringify(shippingAddress));

      return {
        ...state,
        cart: { ...state.cart, shippingAddress },
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Create the default dispatch function
const defaultDispatch: React.Dispatch<Action> = () => initialState;

// Create the Store context
const Store = React.createContext({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: defaultDispatch,
});

// Create the StoreProvider component
function StoreProvider(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<React.Reducer<AppState, Action>>(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );
  return <Store.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }} {...props} />;
}

// Export the Store and StoreProvider
export { Store, StoreProvider };
```

Product.ts

```
export type Product = {
  _id: string
    name: string
    slug: string
    image: string
    category: string
    brand: string
    price: number
    countInStock: number
    description: string
    rating: number
    numReviews: number
  }
```

The product are shown using API.

Answer (score 0):

I have scanned through your code and there are a few areas where your problems may lie. I would first check if the CART_ADD_ITEM action is dispatched correctly: In the addToCartHandler function of the ProductItem component, make sure that the dispatch function is called with the correct action type and payload. Verify that convertProductToCartItem returns the expected CartItem object. Hope, that helps. If not let me know.